# Getting node values from XML and adding them to array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, arrays, nodes

My XML looks like this:

```
<photo>photo1.jpg</photo>
<photo>photo2.jpg</photo>
```

I can get the value of each photo node by doing something like:

```
var myPhoto = $(this).find('photo').text();
```

I'm trying to get an array of nodes like so:

```
myPhotoArray.push(myPhoto);
```

When I push this to an array how do I add a comma separator for each node? It prints all the node values out on one line (photo1.jpgphoto2.jpg) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `join` when you output:

```
myPhotoArray.join(",");
```

Actually, the comma is the default separator, so you could leave it out:

```
myPhotoArray.join();
```